# Clone of DataSet

Tags: c#

If i make clone of DataSet what its means it will give only structure or it will give structure with details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataSet.Clone - Copies the structure of the DataSet, including all DataTable schemas, relations, and constraints. **Does not copy any data.**

Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.clone.aspx)

If you use DataSet.Copy Method, it copies both the structure and data for this DataSet.

Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.copy.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a dataset Copies the structure of the DataSet, including all DataTable schemas, relations, and constraints. Does not copy any data as Copy method of dataset does.
Moewover using Dataset.clone() creates new instance of the same object.